# Objective-C formatting string for boolean?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, string-formatting

What formatter is used for boolean values?

EDIT:

Example: `NSLog(@" ??", BOOL_VAL);`, what is `??` ?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert to strings (since there are only two possibilities, it isn't hard):

```
NSLog(@" %s", BOOL_VAL ? "true" : "false");
```

I don't think there is a format specifier for boolean values.

Comment: Shouldn't the output strings be: "Yes" and "No" :P

Comment: Or "Cake" and "No cake". Whatever suits you.

Comment: I love cake and no cake! I am going to replace all my x?@"YES":@"NO" code with x?@"Cake":@"No Cake" immediately :D -- well, at least for my object descriptions anyway ;)

Comment: Or TheCakeIsALie and TheCakeIsNotALie.

Comment: See my answer to wrap this in a neat macro.

Comment: %hhd is the proper way to display Boolean value as integer flag as 0 or 1 . 0 is false 1 is for true .

Comment: @InnaKamoze thank you! I find this solution much more satisfying for some reason.

Answer (score 72):

I would recommend

```
NSLog(@"%@", boolValue ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

because, um, `BOOL`s are called `YES` or `NO` in Objective-C.

Comment: It seems an obvious utility spot for a macro or a function (if only to avoid the propagation of string literals throughout the app).

Comment: Only you don't really need to to avoid "propagation" of such strings - as ObjC  coallescs same-valued instances of immutable strings (and other objects) - such that only one copy resides in memory. Macro is OK, function is OK, and copy-and-paste are OK too.

Answer (score 58):

Use the integer formatter `%d`, which will print either `0` or `1`:

```
NSLog(@"%d", myBool);
```

Answer (score 24):

In Objective-C, the `BOOL` type is just a signed char. From `<objc/objc.h>`:

```
typedef signed char BOOL;
#define YES         (BOOL)1
#define NO          (BOOL)0
```

So you can print them using the `%d` formatter But that will only print a `1` or a `0`, not `YES` or `NO`.

Or you can just use a string, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Won't %c try to print the ASCII character 0 or 1 both of which are control characters?

Answer (score 23):

Add this inline function to your `.h` file:

```
static inline NSString* NSStringFromBOOL(BOOL aBool) {
    return aBool? @"YES" : @"NO";
}
```

Now you are ready to go...

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromBOOL(BOOL_VAL));
```

Answer (score 5):

Format strings for use with NSLog and [NSString stringWithFormat] are documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

BOOL/bool/boolean are not even mentioned...

Comment: That's very well hidden on the apple dev site.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way to do this is:

```
NSLog(@" %@", @(BOOL_VAL));
```

> @(expression)

Dynamically evaluates the boxed expression and returns the appropriate object literal based on its value (i.e. NSString for const char*, NSNumber for int, etc.).

Comment: Yeap, it converts the Bool in to 1s and 0s accordingly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below function and pass it the `BOOL` value and method will return back the `NSString`

```
- (NSString *)boolValueToString:(BOOL)theBool {
    if (theBool == 0)
        return @"NO"; // can change to No, NOOOOO, etc
    else
        return @"YES"; // can change to YEAH, Yes, YESSSSS etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a category of NSString with this

```
+ (instancetype)stringWithBool:(BOOL)boolValue {
return boolValue ? @"YES" : @"NO";
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[NSString stringWithBool:boolValue];
```