# How to use NSLog to print out BOOL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSLog to print some debug information. For BOOL, I can use %d, but I am wondering if this is a standard way?

Comment: Yup it is standard way. Because BOOL hold 0 and 1 value for TRUE and FALSE.

Answer (score 10):

Use this :

```
NSLog(@"VALUE IS : %@", (YOUR_CONDITION) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Answer (score 6):

%@ is for objects. BOOL is not an object. You should use %d.

It will print out 0 for FALSE/NO and 1 for TRUE/YES.

```
NSlog(@"%d",yourBool)
```

Another way to do.

```
NSLog(flag ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Swift, you can do like this

```
print("Is check = \(yourBool)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use %i if I want just a 0/1 or I will use `NSLog(@"%@",(b?@"YES:@"NO"));` if I want it to print YES/NO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
BOOL flag = 1; //your bool value 
NSLog(@"%@", StringFromBoolean(flag));
```

This will print YES. If bool is 0, the log will be NO. Put this in .pch file so that you can use it everywhere inside your app.

```
  #define StringFromBoolean (return value ? @"YES" : @"NO")
```

Comment: Your `#define` is wrong. No semi-colon needed, should be enclosed in parentheses instead of curly braces.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks for the correction. I have edited the answer. please check.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: There is a static inline function found in cocos3d. We can create a macro and use it here. I forgot to define the macro.

Comment: Don't call it NS anything, either -- prefixes are namespaces in Cocoa. Call it `BOOLToNSString()`

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Guess its okay now! Please check :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition in `objc.h`:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#define OBJC_BOOL_DEFINED


#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

So `BOOL` is signed char and you can you `%d` to print it's value. 
 If you want to print like true and false then you have to check the `BOOL` value. See **`FaJitendra Deore`**'s answer

Answer (score -1):

@Adam : I found a way to get the Output of the BOOL varibale. Since it takes one bit as input/Output. You can use the following code.

```
BOOL flag=TRUE;
NSLog(@" %s", flag ? "true" : "false");
```

This will return true because flag is set true and vice versa.

You can get more brief explanation here [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603831/1625214)

Comment: What is wrong in the above code. Atleast the person should comment it which making an answer as negative. Above is a verfied code work in XCode.